# Central Limit Theorem with two iid

Tags: central-limit-theorem

Suppose$\left \{ X_1,\dots,X_n  \right \}$  is a sequence of independent and identically distributed(i.i.d) random variables
with finite expected value $E[X_i]=\mu _{x}$ and variance  $Var[X_i]=\sigma_x^{2}$. And $\left \{ \alpha _1,\dots,\alpha _n  \right \}$  is another sequence of i.i.d random variables with finite expected value $E[X_i]=\mu _{\alpha }$ and variance  $Var[X_i]=\sigma_\alpha ^{2}$.Then, as $n$ approaches infinity, can we prove the random variables $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha _iX_i$ converge in  to a normal distribution ${\mathcal {N}}(u,\sigma ^{2})$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

Your normalization is wrong. [For eample, $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$ itself does not converge!].

If $(\alpha_i)$ is independent of $(X_i)$ then $(\alpha_iX_i)$ is also i.i.d. with finite variance and standard CLT applies. Otherwise, you cannot assert anything about $ \sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha _iX_i$

Comment: Thanks very much for your valuable answer.I'm a math novice.Could you give me some instrctions on how to prove this conclusion:"If (αi) is independent of (Xi) then (αiXi) is also i.i.d. with finite variance and mean."Thanks again.

Comment: An easy way of proving this is to use characteristic functions.